# Vertex array is too large. A sprite mesh may not have more than 65535 vertices. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, svg

i try to use svg file in unity

i set up vectorgraphics 2.00 in packagemanager

but importing file error is occured

my svgfile max size is  vertexes 250 billions and 7mb

i know mesh max vertex 400 billions but i don't know sprite max vertex

avarge size 1600kb picture [this](http://blogattach.naver.net/099c15a6bdeded311ef29dab92720c77d782779d74/20200810_131_blogfile/jinsw1081_1597040838027_B20m1t_svg/vertebra_order-5-8.svg)

```
Vertex array is too large. A sprite mesh may not have more than 65535 vertices.
UnityEngine.Sprite:OverrideGeometry(Vector2[], UInt16[])
Unity.VectorGraphics.VectorUtils:BuildSprite(List`1, Rect, Single, Alignment, Vector2, UInt16, Boolean) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0.0-preview.12/Runtime/VectorSprite.cs:119)
Unity.VectorGraphics.Editor.SVGImporter:BuildSpriteFromGeometry(List`1, Rect) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0.0-preview.12/Editor/SVGImporter.cs:344)
Unity.VectorGraphics.Editor.SVGImporter:OnImportAsset(AssetImportContext) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0.0-preview.12/Editor/SVGImporter.cs:317)
UnityEditor.Experimental.AssetImporters.ScriptedImporter:GenerateAssetData(AssetImportContext)
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:ProjectWindowDrag(HierarchyProperty, Boolean)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

```
 public static Sprite BuildSprite(List<Geometry> geoms, Rect rect, float svgPixelsPerUnit, Alignment alignment, Vector2 customPivot, UInt16 gradientResolution, bool flipYAxis = false)
    {
        // Generate atlas
        var texAtlas = GenerateAtlasAndFillUVs(geoms, gradientResolution);

        List<Vector2> vertices;
        List<UInt16> indices;
        List<Color> colors;
        List<Vector2> uvs;
        List<Vector2> settingIndices;
        FillVertexChannels(geoms, 1.0f, texAtlas != null, out vertices, out indices, out colors, out uvs, out settingIndices, flipYAxis);

        Texture2D texture = texAtlas != null ? texAtlas.Texture : null;

        if (rect == Rect.zero)
        {
            rect = VectorUtils.Bounds(vertices);
            VectorUtils.RealignVerticesInBounds(vertices, rect, flipYAxis);
        }
        else if (flipYAxis)
        {
            VectorUtils.FlipVerticesInBounds(vertices, rect);

            // The provided rect should normally contain the whole geometry, but since VectorUtils.SceneNodeBounds doesn't
            // take the strokes into account, some triangles may appear outside the rect. We clamp the vertices as a workaround for now.
            VectorUtils.ClampVerticesInBounds(vertices, rect);
        }

        var pivot = GetPivot(alignment, customPivot, rect, flipYAxis);

        // The Sprite.Create(Rect, Vector2, float, Texture2D) method is internal. Using reflection
        // until it becomes public.
        var spriteCreateMethod = typeof(Sprite).GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { typeof(Rect), typeof(Vector2), typeof(float), typeof(Texture2D) }, null);
      //it is error part
```

var sprite = spriteCreateMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { rect, pivot, svgPixelsPerUnit, texture }) as Sprite;

```
                    //it is error part  
            sprite.OverrideGeometry(vertices.ToArray(), indices.ToArray());
```

Comment: Looks like you'll need to simplify the file you're importing before you import it.

Comment: @RobertLongson 
Is SVG cropping simple?
If you cut an svg, can you make sure that the relationship between the positions of each other is not broken when showing different svgs on the screen?

Comment: Not really. You might find that an SVG editor such as Inkscape has some facilities to simplify SVG files. Cutting and reassembling is too broad for a Q&A here you'd need to try it and ask a more specific question.

Comment: You can change the [`Mesh.indexFormat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-indexFormat.html) mesh indexer format to `UInt32` which allows up to `4,294,967,295` but you really shouldn't start to use reflection ... looks like in general you should take a different route there

Comment: Why don't you e.g. use the correct overload of [`Sprite.Create(Texture2D, Rect, Vector2, float)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) ... ?